# Adding Google Analytics code to the <head> tag of specific pages

Tags: php

I want to add Google Analytics code snippet between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags of some relevant pages of my WordPress website. Adding the code snippet to the header.php file will affect all the pages of the website what I do not want. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can add the snippet directly to `header.php`, a better choice is probably the `wp_head` action which should be triggered in any well-made, modern theme.

Using this hook allows you to insert the snippet without actually modifying your theme. It might look something like this:

```
function wpse_282929_conditionally_print_ga_snippet() {
    if ( ! some_conditional_tag() ) {
        return;
    }

    ?>

    {GA Snippet Here}

    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_282929_conditionally_print_ga_snippet' );
```

Where `! some_conditional_tag()` gets replaced by the appropriate conditional that would indicate you DO NOT WANT to print the snippet, and `{GA Snippet Here}` obviously gets replaced with your specific GA snippet.

WordPress provides a number of conditional tags to determine what kind of page your visitor is currently on.

In fact, there are too many to list here, but you can find a complete listing on the [Conditional Tags page in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

As for where to include this code - if you are already working within a custom theme, you can just add it to your `functions.php` file.

If not, I would probably recommend creating a must-use plugin. To do so, first create the `mu-plugins` directory within `wp-content` if it does not already exist. Next, create a file called `ga-snippet.php` within the `mu-plugins` directory and include your GA snippet function there.

Answer (score 2):

The header.php is the right place, but you'll need one more thing: a condition. This way you can decide on which pages to place the code and on which not to. You can check that via [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

```
<?php
$relevant_pages = array('slug1', 'slug2');
if (is_page($relevant_pages)) {
    ?>
    GA snippet
    <?php
}
?>
</head>
```